# H2DB - executeUpdate() returns 0 or 1 on DELETE depending on table definition

Tags: jdbc, h2

I wonder if someone could explain the behaviour of the H2 JDBC driver when deleting an entry from a rather simple table.

When using the following table definition, the method `executeUpdate()` for a `PreparedStatement` instance returns `1` if one entry has been deleted (expected behaviour).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "MATERIAL" (
    "CODE" VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    "NAME" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

When adding a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on the `CODE` column, the same method returns `0` although the entry gets deleted successfully (behaviour not expected).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "MATERIAL" (
    "CODE" VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    "NAME" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("CODE")
);
```

Most interestingly, when adding an `INT` typed column to serve as `PRIMARY KEY` the return value is `1` again:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "MATERIAL" (
    "ID" INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    "CODE" VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    "NAME" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);
```

Is someone able to reconstruct this behaviour and probably somehow explain it to me?

I have included the current version of H2 DB using maven.

EDIT:

If I eventually add a `UNIQUE` constraint for the `CODE` column, the return value is `0` again ...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "MATERIAL" (
    "ID" INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    "CODE" VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "NAME" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("CODE")
);
```

EDIT 2:

The query used to delete an entry looks like the following (used in `PreparedStatement`):

```
DELETE FROM MATERIAL WHERE CODE = ?
```

SOLUTION:

I'm sorry to have you bothered with this. Actually, there was no problem with the table definition or the JDBC driver. It was my test data - from earlier testing I had wanted to INSERT two entries having the same `CODE`. It was a multiple row insert - obviously this failed, when `CODE` was the PK or having a UNIQUE index. Thus, in this cases `executeUpdate()` could only return `0` because there was no data in the table at all.

Comment: Please Show the query

Comment: No hope you used `'?'` (with apostrophes) as it got deleted. Something for the h2database.com then.

Comment: I checked - there are no apostrophes around the `?` ... acutally it doesn't work with.